# How far can I get with Vue.js by just importing from the url?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Say I only import this file in a script tag.

What does Vue.js has to offer as a technology that I cannot access by referring only to:

```
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

After some more research, I've found Vue.js has a CDN for vue-router.

```
<!-- vue-router -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

I wanna be able to use the pattern

```
<template>
<script>
<style>
```

..but I don't want to import or installl anything else.

Comment: Really depends on what you want to do. You will not have a lot of things, e.g vuex or the router.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to learn how to make an app in Vue.js first as a single page. Then I can move to splitting into xyz... Docs in most places quickly move from a basic single page app to importing Vue components. I'm like... Ok. I'm still trying to find out how much I can squeeze out of just one file before all this extra stuff.

Comment: Can I ask why you are not wanting to install anything? Would be good for you to get familiar using the terminal.

Comment: Similar to the reason for an engine with less moving parts.

Comment: Fair enough, answer below will give you the reason why you need some of those moving parts though.

Comment: I am for certain taking your advice though. It is the ultimate destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

But it's only possible in a `.vue` file which is compiled by webpack, browserify or rollup. It's not possible to do that by just import vue.js in a html file.